# Run java standalone application automatically

Tags: java, operating-system

I had written a java standalone console based application.
Is it possible to run that application automatically at a particular time?
it is a kind of automation program which i wanted to run every day.

Comment: yes its possible, but thats an OS question, not a particular java question

Comment: on windows platform.

Comment: search for windows + task scheduler ;-)

Comment: I disagree that this is an OS specific question since this can also be achieved in other ways, see my answer

Comment: for windows use task scheduler and on linux use cron job

Comment: i created a jar file of my package.. and using a batch file i m running that file.. whenever i double click on .bat file.. it runs but using scheduler it opens and blinks and closes... its not running or starting that file

Answer (score 0):

If you add Spring to your application, you could leave it always running and control the scheduling independently from the OS.

You need to use this annotation: `@EnableScheduling`

And the method that you need to run everyday (let's say at 2:30 am) will have:

`@Scheduled(cron = "30 2 * * *")`

[More information about Spring scheduling here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html)

Comment: well it may have its uses, no doubt. But using it they way you suggested, is a really bad practice in my opinion. If you develop a batch controlling app this may be perfect. But if you have a simple app, annotating the main method with that is really awkward. Nobody knows when the app is really doing something. If the system gets rebooted, you have to start the app again (if you automate this, the whole thing becomes a farce ;-)
If a app is running shouldnt be decided by the app itself. But thats my opinion ;-)

Comment: imho, the time a job needs to run is usually related to business logic, so I’d prefer to have it in the code. The OS responsibility then comes down to just keep the app running. This decision depends on much more information than the question provides anyway. It's just my opinion too :)